# loop in the nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I have a nested dictionary. Sometimes it contains more than two attachments. How can I loop through the dictionary to get the following values in the variables ?

```
dict = {'result': [{'a1': 'one', 'a2': 'two', 'a3': '2'},
                  {'b1': 'three', 'b2': 'one', 'b3': '5'}]}
```

```
 res1 = one
 res2 = two
 res3 = 2

 res1 = three
 res2 = one
 res3 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store each value in different variable then I would suggest to append those values in a list.

The code to access those values are:

```
dictt = {'result': [{'a1': 'one', 'a2': 'two', 'a3': '2'},
              {'b1': 'three', 'b2': 'one', 'b3': '5'}]}
for key, value in dictt.items() :
    for i in range(2):
        for item in value[i].values():
            print(item)
```

The ouptut of this is:

```
one
two
2
three
one
5
```

Comment: the value of the range is unknown, sometimes it is 2, sometimes it is more. How to be in this case?

Comment: @booblik use this if the value of range is unknown:
range(len(value)) instead of range(2)

Answer (score 0):

as to loop through the dictionary to get the following values in the variables

```
 dict1 = {'result': [{'a1': 'one', 'a2': 'two', 'a3': '2'},{'b1': 'three', 'b2': 'one', 'b3': '5'}]}
    for j in dict1['result']:#acessing the elements using key value
        print([(j[k]) for k in j])
```

output:

```
['one', 'two', '2']
['three', 'one', '5']
```

NOTE: please don't give dict as dictionary name.

to assign the values to a variable:

```
dict1 = {'result': [{'a1': 'one', 'a2': 'two', 'a3': '2'},{'b1': 'three', 'b2': 'one', 'b3': '5'}]}
l=[]#appending the values of a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3
l1={}#dict to store the newly assigned variable
for j in dict1['result']:
    s=[(j[k]) for k in j]
    l.append(s)
for z in range(3):
    key=str("res"+str(z))#to create keys dynamically
    l1[key]=[l[0][z], l[1][z]]#alloting the values stored in l

print(l1)
```

you will get this as output:

```
{'res0': ['one', 'three'], 'res1': ['two', 'one'], 'res2': ['2', '5']}
```

Comment: How do I assign values from a list to variables?

`res1 = one`
`res2 = two`
`res3 = 2`

`res1 = three`
`res2 = one`
`res3 = 5`

Comment: refer my answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @booblik If my answer solved your query, I request you to accept my answer.